# What is the font used in the new Spotify interface? Looking for an alternative for web

Tags: font-identification

Spotify recently rolled out their some design changes with darker design and new font for their desktop application (version 0.9.8).

Can someone tell me what font are they using, and if there is a similar alternative on google?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google font Alternative to Proxima nova:

[Montserrat](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Montserrat)

[image]

An article released on "[Fonts Similar To 'Proxima Nova'](http://www.fontspring.com/similar/mark-simonson-studio/proxima-nova)" if Montserrat doesnt work.

[Proxima nova](https://typekit.com/fonts/proxima-nova) is the font used and there have been some articles about it.

[image]

Released articles that I found when I searched for it on Monday and wanted to know too (I also started a discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) about it):

- "[Exclusive: Major Spotify redesign revealed](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2014-04/02/new-spotify)"
- "[Spotify's New Redesign Is Beautiful and Functional](http://mashable.com/2014/04/02/spotify-redesign/)"
- "[Spotify Font](http://fontmeme.com/spotify-font/)"

Just in case someone runs across this and wants to know more about Spotify history of fonts:

[image]

- logotype is **Gotham** by [Hoefler & Co.](http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/overview/) per 2013 article source in regards to Spotify: "[Spotify brand and website](http://fontsinuse.com/uses/3554/spotify-brand-and-website)"

[image]

Just an FYI if you did a Google search ([font used in Spotify new design](https://www.google.com/search?q=font%20used%20in%20spotify&oq=font%20used%20in%20spo&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5528j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=font%20used%20in%20spotify%20new%20design&spell=1)) you would have found all the information.

Answer (score 2):

Like the other users have answered, Spotify uses Proxima Nova for the desktop and web applications.

One good tool for future reference, granted it that the font you need to find is on a HTML webpage, is the WhatFont extension for Chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en

> **The easiest way to identify fonts on web pages.**
>
> What is the easiest way to find out the fonts used in a webpage? Firebug and Webkit Inspector are easy enough to use for developers. However, for others, this should not be necessary. With this extension, you could inspect web fonts by just hovering on them. It is that simple and elegant.
>
> It also detects the services used for serving the web fonts. Supports Typekit and Google Font API.
>
> Recommended by Wired WebMonkey, Lifehacker, and SwissMiss.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> font-family: proxima_nova,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

Proxima nova. IRC it's an adobe typekit font, but maybe not.

https://typekit.com/fonts/proxima-nova

This is assuming you're talking about what's used for paragraph text on their homepage.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I understand they've now dropped  Prixima nova in favour of LL Circular

*(according to fontsinuse.com - Apr 22nd, 2015)*

Answer (score 1):

Circular

[image]

https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/circular-std-book

This is the font used, love it, check it out. Got it from the source code on SPOTIFY WEB!

Comment: When posting a font suggestion please make sure to include a screenshot preview of the font.

Comment: @Mᴏɴᴋᴇʏ si señor!

Comment: Done deal I will, henceforth!